# Div not including image properties

Tags: css, image, html

I have 2 problems, but the second one can't be address until the first one is corrected. The page was looking and working as intended but when I came to work and started working on the page, it seems to be broken. I am using the same browser in both locations.

The problem is that the background for the div is set to auto, like all my other divs on the same page, but the last one for some reason is not spanning to the bottom of the image.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3iXu.png

```
<div class="items">

<h2><a name="friday"><a href="#">Friday catch of the day:</a></a></h2> 

    <img src="images/catch.png" align="right" alt="Sage-rubbed Double-cut Pork Chop" />

    <p><span class="title">Alaskan Halibut with a Rich Loire Valley Beurre Blanc Sauce</span> - served with mashed purple Peruvian potatoes and haricot verts.</p>

    <p><span class="title">Recommended pairing:</span> '98 Passi Emilio Vineyards Sauvignon Blanc</p>


</div>
```

CSS

```
.items {
    margin: 20px;
    height: auto;
    width: 910px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
    padding: 10px;  
    z-index: 1;
}
.items img {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    float: right;
    border-radius: 6px;
    width: auto;
    padding: 8px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.items p {
    font-family: 'PT Sans';
    font-size: 16px;    
}
.items a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;      
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.items img {
    float: left;   <---- ???
    margin-right: 10px;
    float: right;   <---- ???
    border-radius: 6px;
    width: auto;
    padding: 8px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

You're floating **right** and **left**. Choone one. You also need to clear your floats afterwards for normal flow to resume

Comment: How did I miss that? Thank you! Also when you say clearing my floats do you mean using <div class="clear"></div> and setting clear to both?

Answer (score 0):

add `overflow: auto` to items class.

```
.items {
    margin: 20px;
    height: auto;
    width: 910px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
    padding: 10px;  
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be adding an empty `div` and `clear: both`

HTML:

```
<div class="items">
    ...    
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f22GN/)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. Save this code as a snippet for any future development. Just add the class .clearfix to the parent container if it contains floating childs and you're good to go :)

```
.clearfix{*zoom:1;}
.clearfix:before,.clearfix:after{display:table;content:"";line-height:0;}
.clearfix:after{clear:both;}
```